# SSL certificate issue

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am still new to system administration

I have Debian Load balancing server. we are using nginx for SSL sites and apache for non ssl.

I have created new virtual host for new website on nginx also reloaded the nginx for 443 port. there are no errors on nginx settings

Also created virtual host settings for port 80.

the site works perfectly fine on http(port 80) but it does not work for port 443

i have tried using telnet for private ip address and it connects properly but when i tries to connect public ip address for 443 port it does not connect.

```
telnet 113.52.9.43 443 Trying 113.52.9.43... telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

But when i try to use telnet on server using private ip address it connects properly

I checked the port connection - yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports and it says 443 is closed I did check with third party supplier(who looks after our firewall) and they say it is open

is there anything else i need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Describe "does not connect".  Immediate "connection refused" or a timeout?  Packet captures will probably be helpful.

Comment: telnet 113.52.9.43 443
Trying 113.52.9.43...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

But when i try to use telnet on server using private ip address it connects properly

Comment: I checked the port connection - yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports and it says 443 is closed I did check with third party supplier(who looks after our firewall) and they say it is open

Comment: How is the public IP address routed to the private one?

Comment: check `netstat -tulpn` maybe nginx listens to the wrong interface for port 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds very much to be a fierwall issue. Your check result clearly shows that the port 443 is not open at the firewall or may be nat rule is pointing to wrong server ip. I'm assuming the server has only one interface and a single ip address and it is listening on port 443.

What you can do is email your check results/findings to the third party, who is responsible for the firewall and request them to check the firewall configuration again. It is important that you send the check results to them so that they see that you have a point.

Comment: yes it was indeed firewall issue and finally they admitted that it was a typo mistake from their end. It just i wasted my half day.